# How can I make Eclipse WindowBuilder parse an inherited JFrame?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

I have a class BaseWindow with a JFrame mainFrame, and a bunch of methods that work on mainFrame. Actual windows in my app are made by extending BaseWindow.

The class extending BaseWindow inherits mainFrame, and that somehow prevents window builder from "seeing" it when it parses the code. All I see in window builder's design tab is an empty window, but when I run the code everything works fine.

How can I make this approach work with window builder, or "trick" window builder into parsing mainFrame? Here is an example class extending BaseWindow:

```
package GUIApp;

//took out the imports to save space

class SampleWindowOne extends BaseWindow{


    public JLabel txtSampleText;
    public JButton btnMagicButton;

    public SampleWindowOne() {
        initialize();
    }

    public void run(){
        mainFrame.setBounds(getCenteredBounds());
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initialize() {

        mainFrame = new JFrame();
        mainFrame.setBounds(100,100,700,525);
        mainFrame.setTitle("Sample Window One");
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        txtSampleText = new JLabel();
        txtSampleText.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        txtSampleText.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        txtSampleText.setText("Sample Window");
        txtSampleText.setBounds(12, 50, 674, 51);
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(txtSampleText);

        JTextArea txtrLoremIpsumDolor = new JTextArea();
        txtrLoremIpsumDolor.setEditable(false);
        txtrLoremIpsumDolor.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        txtrLoremIpsumDolor.setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        txtrLoremIpsumDolor.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        txtrLoremIpsumDolor.setLineWrap(true);
        txtrLoremIpsumDolor.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...");
        txtrLoremIpsumDolor.setBounds(57, 131, 609, 296);
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(txtrLoremIpsumDolor);

        btnMagicButton = new JButton("End Program");
        btnMagicButton.setEnabled(false);
        btnMagicButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                requestTerminate();
            }
        });
        btnMagicButton.setBounds(257, 451, 175, 25);
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(btnMagicButton);

    }
}
```

Comment: `txtrLoremIpsumDolor.setBounds(57, 131, 609, 296);`??

Comment: Note: I don't use window builders, but I do a lot of Swing coding, and that line above should never ever be present because it constrains the natural behavior of the JTextArea. JTextAreas belong within JScrollPanes, and to constrain its size in this way, you prevent the text area from expanding -- meaning the scroll bars will never work. I suggest that you abandon use of windows builders until you understand the underlying library better.

Comment: Good info, Hovercraft. I could definitely benefit from a deeper understanding of Swing, but for the moment I just need to get WYSIWYG design capabilities working again. I'm writing code for a class where the GUI design we have been taught so far is very rudimentary and exclusively done through window builder, so my group members and I kind of need to be able to use it for the current project.

Comment: So let me see if I understand your predicament. You've created some GUI-creation code code by hand, since it's quite obvious that none of the code within the init method was created by the windows builder program, and you want to see if this hand-made code can be used within the windows builder, as if it were a drag and drop GUI component?

Comment: Actually, the initialize code does come from window builder. The problem is that when mainFrame is inherited from BaseWindow rather than declared within the class SampleWindowOne, window builder can no longer parse it. If I add the line JFrame mainFrame; at the beginning of the class window builder works fine again, but the inherited methods that work on mainFrame break. My current workaround is to put the line JFrame mainFrame; at the beginning of the class, do what I need to do in window builder, then remove that line again before I run the code.

Answer (score 1):

**I'm sure you're past that now,** but for others searching solution to this:

In eclipse go to:
**Window -> Preferences -> Window Builder(tree) -> Swing -> Code Generation**

1. Set initGUI method from the combo box of "Method name for new statements" at the top of the page. (you can also try  to set another method name)
2. In "Variable generation" section, click **once** on third tab: "Init. Field" so that you can see its' square filled with v sign(and the other tabs have an empty square).
3. Click ok.
4. Restart eclipse.
5. Create a method named initGUI as follows:

   ```
   private void initGUI() {

   }
   ```
6. Copy **all** your code from the constructor to that method.
7. Call that method from your constructor:

   ```
   public WindowTest()
   {
       initGUI();
   }
   ```
8. Go to window builder design by clicking: "Design" at the bottom of the editor.
9. Click a lot of reparse if necessary.
10. Now add one component (JButton for instance) to the window, and watch it go into iniGUI method. **Once you've seen that happens** - it is safe to take out code lines that are not realted to GUI from that method and put them in the constructor if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a way to trick window builder into working! I changed the constructor from:

```
public SampleWindowOne() {
    initialize();
}
```

to:

```
public SampleWindowOne() {
    JFrame mainFrame;
    initialize();
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone with their own code.

Edit: not fully solved after all, see below. I will update if I find a better solution.

Edit2: Okay, after a good night's sleep the solution is pretty obvious. I now declare a separate JFrame at the beginning of the class. I add all my elements to this frame instead of mainFrame, and at the end of initialize I put

```
mainFrame = newFrame;
```

Comment: Hmm. On further experimentation it seems that window builder now parses the existing code, but crashes when I try to add new elements. It is able to modify existing ones. Still not a complete solution.

Comment: This code `public SampleWindowOne() {
    JFrame mainFrame;
    initialize();
}` declares a local variable that is never initialised and will go out of scope at the end of the constructor. It won't achieve anything good. Further, you seem to be 'coding by magic' (slapping random statements into the IDE in the hope they will magically work) ..which *never* works.

Comment: I realize that variable goes out of scope after the constructor is finished running. I made a guess that inserting that line would "trick" window builder into being able to parse the JFrame in question, and I was correct. Declaring mainFrame within the class makes window builder look for it while parsing the initialize method. The issue is that although window builder can now parse the JFrame ,it can't add new elements.  My hope was that someone with experience with this particular design tool could weigh in on the appropriate way to accomplish what I am trying to do.

Comment: It may be worth further clarifying that my code is functional and works as intended, the issue is trying to get window builder to work with it.

Comment: Okay, one last comment to point out my second edit above. Problem solved, thanks for the input.